# Convert KeyEvent.VK_[value] to String

Tags: java, keyevent

Given an integer which comes from `KeyEvent.VK_[value]`, such as `KeyEvent.VK_SPACE` or `KeyEVENT.VK_F3`, I'd like to convert it to the String of the key.

For example
`keyIntToString(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)` would return `"Space"`

How can I do this?

---

I've tried

```
KeyEvent.getKeyText(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
```

In the terminal, if I print that, I get "Space". In Eclipse if I print that, I get "?". In a JLabel if I display that, I get a square.

What I really want is to get it into a JLabel. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
String keyString = KeyEvent.getKeyText(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
System.out.println("keyString " + keyString);
```

Also you can use [`getChar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar%28%29) method in KeyEvent

Comment: That doesn't work.   System.out.println(KeyEvent.getKeyText(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)); prints out "?". Also, I don't see how I could use getChar() to write the method I am trying to write as indicated in the question.

Comment: wired. I'm getting "Space"

Comment: WEIIIIRD. On Terminal I get "Space" but in Eclipse I get "?"

Comment: and on JLabel I get a square.

Comment: try keep it in a string then add it to jlabel.

Comment: You should try Eclipse and also JLabel and you'll get the same result